# Goal in Journey Builder not Evaluating

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I am trying to define a goal based on an engagement metrics. Specifically i have a Journey that uses a Data Extension as a Source. Then I have created another Data Extension where i keep the tracking data (in my case opens) which i retrieve via SQL and shows me the people that have opened the emails send from the Journey.

I want to be able to set the goal in my journey for 50% of the population to have opened the email.

I have created a 1:Many relationship in Contact Builder and in the Goal i am using this secondary data extension for defining the Goal Criteria.

Print screens below. Goal for this Journey stays at 0% in the UI. I can confirm that the SQL pulls the correct data.

Giulietta.

[image]

Comment: I see that your contacts are always at the 1 day wait. How long have they been there? The goal evaluation depends upon whether a goal is set to remove the contacts from the journey. Please check this link: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_goals.htm&type=5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The goal evaluation depends upon whether it is set to remove the contacts from the journey or not.

If the exit option is not set, the goal is evaluated each time a wait period expires. In your case, at the end of the 1 day wait.

I would suggest that you update your wait activities to 1 or 2 minutes so that the goal can be evaluated quickly.

Reference: 
[Goals](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_goals.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thanks @Rachid Mamai. I have adjusted the wait period and i can see my goal working as expected.

Comment: Would you mind marking this as an answer if it resolved your problem?